# Trying to write a javascript function inline: doesn't work

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I tried to write down this javascript function in an inline way:

```
function WhichKeyPress(e) {
 if (!e) {
  //if the browser did not pass the event 
  //information to the function, 
  //we will have to obtain it from the 
  //event register
  if (window.event) {
       //Internet Explorer
        e = window.event;
     } else {
       //total failure, we have no 
      //way of referencing the event
       return;
     }
   }
   if (typeof (e.keyCode) == 'number') {
      //DOM
      e = e.keyCode;
    } else if (typeof (e.which) == 'number') {
      //NS 4 compatible
      e = e.which;
    } else if (typeof (e.charCode) == 'number') {
     //also NS 6+, Mozilla 0.9+
      e = e.charCode;
    } else {
      //total failure, we have no way of obtaining the key code
      return;
    }
}
```

It became something like this:

```
Me.Attributes.Add("onkeydown","var evt; if(!e){ evt = window.event;}else{return;} if(typeof(evt.keyCode == 'number'){//do something}else if....."}
```

And it so goes on. 
Needless to say it doesn't work. I've tried other inline javascript functions like this:

```
Me.Attributes.Add("onkeydown","if(event.keyCode == 13){return event.keyCode = 9;} ")
```

It works. But if i do this:

```
Me.Attributes.Add("onkeydown","var cod = event.keyCode; if(cod == 13){return cod = 9;})
```

It won't work.

Can i really write a whole javascript function inline? With variables being declared and everything else?

EDIT: I've read the link that @millimoose provided and i'm trying to use an external .js file in my dll in vs2005 but with no success. Here's wha't i've done so far:

1) Created a 'Scripts' folder with the js file in the dll solution.

2) Set the Build Action to 'EmbeddedResource'

3) Overwrote my OnPreRender method like this:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnPreRender(ByVal e As EventArgs)
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptResource(Me.GetType(), "webControlesUES.Scripts.EnterToTab.js")
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "EnterToTab", "teste()", True)
End Sub
```

4) On my Render method, i've added this:

```
Me.Attributes.Remove("onkeydown")
Me.Attributes.Add("onkeydown", " teste();")
If Me.TextMode = Web.UI.WebControls.TextBoxMode.MultiLine Then
     Me.Attributes.Remove("onkeydown")
End If
```

5) Added this on my AssemblyInfo.vb

```
<Assembly: System.Web.UI.WebResource("webControlesUES.Scripts.EnterToTab.js", "application/x-javascript")>
```

6) Built the solution and added the dll for testing.

But it's not working. Am i forgetting something here?

Comment: Why? Keep the function  in JS code and to attribute add just call to that funciton

Comment: I have to write it inline. It's a dll of custom webcontrols. They inherit from System.Web.UI.

Comment: Webcontrol's DLL can include JS as embedded resource

Comment: "It won't work" is not an error message of anything except maybe Oracle products.

Comment: To expand on what Yuriy mentioned, you can use external JS files from a control library like this: http://jasongaylord.com/blog/embed-javascript-in-custom-asp.net-server-controls

Answer (score 0):

The event object is sent as a parameter to the function also for inline code, but as you don't have any function declaration you need to pick it up from the `arguments` collection instead of as a named parameter.

Example:

```
Me.Attributes.Add("onkeydown","var e=arguments[0];if(e.keyCode == 13){ alert('enter'); }");
```

Comment: I don't think this is entirely accurate.

Comment: @millimoose: Why not?

Comment: In fact it's [patently wrong](http://jsfiddle.net/XQ7VL/). Inline event handlers are wrapped with an implicit function definition. (The HTML5 spec might actually define it as well.) That said, beware the IE incompatibility there.

Comment: That inline event handler functions do in fact have a function declaration and named parameters. The definition looks like this: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#event-handler-attributes. (Look for point 6. in the numbered list a little further down.) It's not necessary to poke into `arguments`. The fact this is specified might also mean newer IEs might not require using `window.event`. (Something your answer also omits for older IEs.)

Comment: Consequently this also means this shouldn't be the problem with the OP's code which makes this answer probably useless.